# how to block forwarding traffic from the physical interface( seth_w0) to VPN interface( tun0)

Tags: vpn, iptables

I have a requirement in which need to block certain processes to consume network data using VPN interface ( tun0).

physical interface(cellular data) -> tun0- >user space program->physical interface-> destination.

pls correct me if i am wrong , the above way the traffic flows though when VPN is enabled.

so if i want to block one particular process network packet not to forwared to tun0 interface, i have applied the iptable rules for both the physical interface and the tun0 interface. still the application is able to use the network data using the tun0 interface.

is there a way to block the traffic at tun0 interface?

Answer (score -1):

dont know which rules you set but maybe this fix

(allow only tun0, reject others)

iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i ! tun0 -j REJECT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o ! tun0 -j REJECT